# Is knockout containerless syntax a smell?

Tags: knockout.js

I feel that using a comment to describe behavior of a view is a smell. As such it doesn't mean that any time you see it, it is bad, it is just suspicious. I try to avoid using it if I can. But often I find that avoid it makes code less readable.

Here is a most common case:

```
<div data-bind="visible: taskIsAssigned, if: taskIsAssigned" class="assignee">
  Assigned to: <span data-bind="text: assignee"></span>
</div>

<!-- ko if: taskIsAssigned -->
<div class="assignee">
  Assigned to: <span data-bind="text: assignee"></span>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I am looking for an advice or a rule of thumb, or hopefully a solution better than two above.

I expected that `if` binding should have hidden the element it decorates, but it doesn't. Maybe I should tweak `if` or add a "`visible_if`" binding that provide such behavior?

Comment: From the small experience I had with it, I would say KO is not that good if you want to keep your HTML code clean. Using HTML comments as part of instructions was one of issues I had with it. No one should ever be worried that removing a comment will break the code. As a side remark, note that `<span data-bind="text: assignee"/>` is wrong syntax, it should be written `<span data-bind="text: assignee"></span>`. The way you're putting it in your example is the usual way developer tools display it, but that's just their way of representing an empty element of the dom.

Comment: avoid using comments in knockout!!! once i had a hard time to figure out, that my application was not working when i was online over a mobile data connection. it appears that some providers optimize html (i.e. remove comments) to increase performance

Comment: Your example is a poor example. There is no need to use containerless in that example. Containerless should be used when you don't want to add an element to the dom just to facilitate data binding

Answer (score 0):

knockout containerless syntax has two main issues

- comments being used to direct actual behaviour: this could be lost in minification processes
- these comments aren't usually taken into account in IDEs indentation, so if you're using multiple levels of containerless syntax you could easily get lost [see this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406362/properly-indent-knockoutjs-virtual-elements)

This is why it should only really be kept for cases where it is necessary (`<select>` and `<li>` tags come to mind).