# Properly indent KnockoutJS virtual elements

Tags: visual-studio, knockout.js, indentation

I just started work on a large KnockoutJS code base in a Visual Studio MVC project. Everything so far seems fairly straightforward except the virtual elements. I understand the need and it is fairly nifty. However because the virtual elements are comments then indentation is all messed up which makes it a terrible pain to read.

Is it possible to convert these to an actual html element or to get Visual Studio/Resharper to indent them correctly?

For instance I have some code like the following which is all at the same indentation level.

```
<!-- ko with: Home -->
<!-- ko with: Model -->
<!-- ko foreach: Items -->
<!-- ko if: IsOpened -->
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-bind="click: $parents[1].SelectItem, css: { 'btn-warning': IsActived }, disable: $root.ItemDetail().IsLoading">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o fa-lg" data-bind="css: { 'text-success': !IsActived() }"></i><span data-bind="text: Title"></span>
</button>
<!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->  
<!-- ko foreach: OtherItems -->
<!-- ko if: IsOpened -->

<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-bind="click: $parents[1].SelectOtherItem, css: { 'btn-warning': IsActived }, disable: $root.OtherItemDetail().IsLoading">
    <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-lg" data-bind="css: { 'text-info': !IsActived() }"></i><span data-bind="text: Title"></span>
</button>
<!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
...
<!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
```

Comment: I was searching quite a lot about this and also for example for any kind of binding-string intellisense. All was unsuccessful so far, I think we just have to live with it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, you **can** use an actual html element instead of the virtual container just to enable you to have better readability and indentation (using `span` or `div`).

Going from your example, I'd do something like this

```
<span data-bind="with:Home">
    <span data-bind="with: Model">
        <span data-bind="foreach: Items">
            <span data-bind="if: IsOpened">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-bind="click: $parents[1].SelectItem, css: { 'btn-warning': IsActived }, disable: $root.ItemDetail().IsLoading">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o fa-lg" data-bind="css: { 'text-success': !IsActived() }"></i><span data-bind="text: Title"></span>
                </button>
            </span>
        </span>  
        <span data-bind="foreach: OtherItems">
            <span data-bind="if: IsOpened">

                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-bind="click: $parents[1].SelectOtherItem, css: { 'btn-warning': IsActived }, disable: $root.OtherItemDetail().IsLoading">
                    <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-lg" data-bind="css: { 'text-info': !IsActived() }"></i><span data-bind="text: Title"></span>
                </button>
            </span>
        </span>
        ...
    </span>
</span>
```

However, the need for such containerless control flow syntax remains for stuff like `select` and `li` elements.
In the cases where you need several nested layers of `select` and `li` as @Zoltán Tamási put it, we'll probably have to live with this.